# A function that checks whether a string has all vowels or not

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def all_vowels(string):
    if 'a' and 'e' and 'i' and 'o' and 'u' in string:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
print(all_vowels('​she is your friend'))
```

---

```
Output:
True
```

Hello, I dont understand why it gives True even though there is no "a" in the string..

Comment: it's evaluating `if "a"` and each subclause separately along with `"u" in string` so everything (non-empty strings are `True`) evaluates to `True`

Comment: `if all(vowel in string for vowel in 'aeiou')`

Comment: ```>>> 'a' and 'e' and 'i' and 'o' and 'u'``` returns ```'u'```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for -

```
def all_vowels(string):
    v = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
    if set(string.split()).intersection(v)==v:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
all_vowels('abcd')
#False

all_vowels('aeiou')
#True
```

This is more efficient that you string search -

1. This takes an intersection between the set of characters in the string and the set of characters in the list of vowels.
2. If the intersection is the same, as the set of vowels, then it means the string has all the vowels and it returns True.
3. This saves u from 2 nested for loops for each string.

Comment: Can we solve it without using list for this time please?

Comment: edited it, check the solution now

Comment: Thanks, but cant we solve it with just string operation?  I mean I know lists and dictionaries, but is there any way to solve it by just modifying my code slightly?

Comment: I think that by using  "  'a' and 'e' and 'i' and 'o' and 'u' in string:  " line I make sure that string has all these wovels(a,e,i,o,u) But it gives true, I dont understand why

Comment: u can, but it would take u 2 for loops . if that is the case then its super simple and u can do it easily. This was similar to the interview question i usually ask when hiring "what is the miniumum number of for loops required to find if the string has vowels or not". thats why i shared the solution that doesnt need explicit for loops

Comment: Is my third comment here wrong?

Comment: Because in operation cant work on multiple variables .. `'a' in 'abcd'` works but not `'a', 'b', 'c' in 'abcd'`. You will need a for loop for that. Or worse, write 5 conditional statements with `and` in between each.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.

Comment: great, glad to help